# Can I override the Thread#start() method as it is not declared as Final?

Tags: java, multithreading

If i want to override the `Thread#start()` method can I?
and if yes will it affect any normal functionality of thread or not?

Comment: Please give more information. Are you talking about Thread.start()? Do you have a special reason that requires you to do this?

Comment: @Elliiot: Yes I am talking about Thread.start().I just want to experiment I am learning Java basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean `Thread.start()`, sure you can override it. But unless you call `super.start()` within it, the thread won't do much anything.

Comment: Why super.start() is required as generally we call it as thread_object.start()

Comment: Well, if you override the `start()`, then the overridden `start()` won't be called unless you call `super.start()` which you've overridden. The thread won't start without.

Comment: why that would not be called as generally whatever method we override is called normally.

Comment: Your conception of overriding seems to be incorrect. Overriding *means* that the overrid*ing* method is called instead of the overrid*den* method. In Java, the overrid*den* method can be called only from within the overrid*ing* method, using the `super.xxx()` syntax. If you don't to it, the overridden method won't be called at all.

Comment: Yes, I know that the overriding method is called. But whatever functionality we write in the overriding method is executed and we do not have to call the overridden method specially.

Comment: This is the code in the overridden method. It is not that spectacular but it does contain important threading stuff, without this code the thread won't behave as expected http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html#671

Comment: Can you write the functionality of `Thread.start()` into the overriding method? It's not impossible, but please note that under the hood, `Thread.start()` will call `private native void start0()`, which eventually hooks the thread into an actual OS thread via the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can override it if you wish.

Depending on what you want to do with the method, it might affect the normal functionality; your question is not very specific in that sense. What you **should** do though is call `super.start()` in your method to make sure that any initialization still takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some languages, Java lets you override just about anything, including Thread.start.  Doing so will certainly affect the normal functionality of the `start` method.  Unlike some languages, Java provides source code, so you can have look at exactly what the origianl `start` method does.

It is generally a good idea to look.  In addition to seeing what your overriding method must do (most simply by calling the super), you can learn a lot about the the platform's design philosophy and a lot about good Java programming.

Perhaps this is why you are overriding `start` in the first place, but I have occasionally found it useful to override methods that don't really ever need overriding simply so I can put in logging messages and get a sense of when they are being called, by what, and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `Thread.start()` but if you dont call `super.start()` it will not create new tread in new stack .

`super.start()` calls a native method `native void start0()` which basically starts new thread in its own stack.

Comment: why it will make new thread, as the function name is still same and it should still call the same run method..?